# Is it possible to develop for Windows Phone 8.1 and 10 on the same machine?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone

I had a Windows Phone 8.1 project running on VS2013. Then, I upgraded to VS2015 and installed the Windows 10 SDK.

After that, when I opened the solution again, there was a message telling me that the project could not be loaded and I'd have to download and install Windows Phone 8.1 SDK.

Done that, everything is working fine, but when I tried to add a WP10 project to the solution it tells me to install the Windows 10 SDK.

Is there a way the two SDKs could be friends and live happily on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Perhaps something went wrong with your VS installation, try repairing it.

Comment: Trying it now. Thanks.

Comment: Haven't looked in Visual Studio, but when I was installing the latest Office, I noticed they default to something like "Upgrade existing Office products." But there is an option to keep existing and install side by side. There may be a similar option in the advanced installer of the SDK that you'll need to look for.

Comment: Once I did an install of the windows 10 sdk.  If I added features to vs 2015 there was an option for windows phone 8.1 sdk

Comment: I chose the **Change** option in **Add/Remove programs**, checked the Windows 10 SDK and now everything's working. That's the same thing I'm almost sure I did the first time, but what matters is that's working now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first got Windows Phone 8.1 SDK installed, then I clicked the **Change** option in **Add/Remove programs**, checked the Windows 10 SDK and now everything's working.

That's the same thing I'm almost sure I did the first time, but what matters is that's working now. =D

Thanks everyone!